# Можно ли данный тест использовать как локальный?

Tags: java, android, junit

Читаю [офф док](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) и вот тут приводится пример инстрментального теста

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class LogHistoryAndroidUnitTest {

public static final String TEST_STRING = "This is a string";
public static final long TEST_LONG = 12345678L;
private LogHistory mLogHistory;

@Before
public void createLogHistory() {
    mLogHistory = new LogHistory();
}

@Test
public void logHistory_ParcelableWriteRead() {
    // Set up the Parcelable object to send and receive.
    mLogHistory.addEntry(TEST_STRING, TEST_LONG);

    // Write the data.
    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    mLogHistory.writeToParcel(parcel, mLogHistory.describeContents());

    // After you're done with writing, you need to reset the parcel for reading.
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);

    // Read the data.
    LogHistory createdFromParcel = LogHistory.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
    List<Pair<String, Long>> createdFromParcelData = createdFromParcel.getData();

    // Verify that the received data is correct.
    assertThat(createdFromParcelData.size(), is(1));
    assertThat(createdFromParcelData.get(0).first, is(TEST_STRING));
    assertThat(createdFromParcelData.get(0).second, is(TEST_LONG));
}
}
```

Но насколько я понимаю что данный тест можно было бы записать и как обычный локальный тест? Зачем он приводится в примере иструментального когда нет очивидной разницы? тогда и не понятно когда использовать один тип тестов а когда другой...